# Rails devise check for authenticate user without filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, devise

Without using `before filter` in `controller` i want to check `user` is authenticated or not, because it force the `user` to be authenticated.
       I am looking for a way how to ask in controller that `user` is authenticated or not, and based on that decide what to send back from the `controller`.

**Current code:**

```
class Api::TestsController < Api::ApiController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
// the filter is force me to be an authenticated user to get access to this controller
end
```

**What i want:**

```
class Api::TestsController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    if current_user
      // do something if the user is authenticated 
    else
      // do something if the user not authenticated
    end
  end
end
```

How can i implement this?
**What i want:**

```
class Api::TestsController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    if current_user then
      // do something if the user is authenticated 
    else
      // do something if the user not authenticated
    end
  end
end
```

How can i implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, use the method [`user_signed_in?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L95) then. Assuming your devise model is `User`.

```
class Api::TestsController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      # do something if the user is authenticated 
    else
      # do something if the user not authenticated
    end
  end
end
```